# Find missing date as compare to calendar

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I am explain problem in short.

```
select distinct  DATE from #Table where   DATE >='2016-01-01'
```

Output :

```
Date 
2016-11-23  
2016-11-22  
2016-11-21  
2016-11-19  
2016-11-18
```

Now i need to find out missing date a compare to our calender dates from year '2016'

i.e. Here date '**2016-11-20**' is missing.

I want list of missing dates.

Thanks for reading this. Have nice day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to generate dates and you have to find missing ones. Below with recursive cte i have done it

```
  ;WITH CTE AS
    (
    SELECT CONVERT(DATE,'2016-01-01') AS DATE1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DD,1,DATE1) FROM CTE WHERE DATE1<'2016-12-31'
    )
    SELECT DATE1 MISSING_ONE FROM CTE
    EXCEPT 
    SELECT * FROM #TABLE1
    option(maxrecursion 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to generate the dates and then find the missing ones.  A recursive CTE is one way to generate a handful of dates.  Another way is to use `master..spt_values` as a list of numbers:

```
with n as (
      select row_number() over (order by (select null)) - 1 as n
      from master..spt_values
     ),
     d as (
      select dateadd(day, n.n, cast('2016-01-01' as date)) as dte
      from n
      where n <= 365
     )
select d.date
from d left join
     #table t
     on d.dte = t.date
where t.date is null;
```

If you are happy enough with *ranges* of missing dates, you don't need a list of dates at all:

```
select date, (datediff(day, date, next_date) - 1) as num_missing
from (select t.*, lead(t.date) over (order by t.date) as next_date
      from #table t
      where t.date >= '2016-01-01'
     ) t
where next_date <> dateadd(day, 1, date);
```

Comment: not working . 1st query giving error invalid date column. next one giving ouput like ...  2016-11-23    -1

Comment: @ShakeerMirza . . . No, the closing parentheses was missing.

Answer (score 1):

Using `CTE` and get all dates in `CTE` table then compare with your table.

```
CREATE TABLE #yourTable(_Values DATE)
INSERT INTO #yourTable(_Values)
SELECT '2016-11-23' UNION ALL 
SELECT '2016-11-22' UNION ALL  
SELECT '2016-11-21' UNION ALL
SELECT '2016-11-19' UNION ALL  
SELECT '2016-11-18'   


DECLARE @DATE DATE = '2016-11-01'
;WITH CTEYear (_Date) AS
(
  SELECT @DATE
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,_Date)
  FROM CTEYear
  WHERE _Date < EOMONTH(@DATE,0)
)

SELECT * FROM CTEYear
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM #yourTable WHERE _Date = _Values)
OPTION(maxrecursion 0)
```

Comment: getting result from 01/01/2016. and so on

Comment: I edited above code.check for NOV month only.Previously I posted for full year 2016